# Oil is leaking to my spark plugs. how do I clean it?

Tags: sparkplugs, oil-leak

I have a 93 Honda Accord and it won't turn over. I listened to see if it was the fuel pump but that was not the problem. I finally removed the valve cover gasket and found about an inch of oil where the spark plugs are and they where covered in oil. How do I clean it?

Comment: It won't turn over?  Usually, that means that you turn the key and hear nothing or just hear clicks which would indicate an electrical problem.  Do you mean it turned over, but wouldn't start?

Answer (score 5):

Spray some brake clean in the plug well. Hold a rag over the plug hole and hit it with compressed air. You could also use a small tube and a fluid extraction pump. Or you could stuff rags down the plug wells until you get all the oil out.

Also you need to replace the sparkplug tube seals (and make sure they're seated around the plug tubes) to keep oil from getting back into the plug well. They generally come with the valve cover gasket kits.